# How to purge Firebase Hosting CDN cache for a path with wildcards or query strings (GET params)?

Tags: firebase, web-hosting, cdn

### Context

I'm having a Cloud Run service, that generates images, hosted via Firebase hosting. I benefits from the included Firebase Hosting CDN. Because, with Firebase hosting:

> Any requested static content is automatically cached on the CDN.

### Creating CDN cache works well

The first time when requesting an image it will be generated on the fly, subsequent requests it will get the CDN-version.

This works amazingly well.

### Purging one explicit URL works too

Sometimes I need to remove all live versions of an image. Therefore, I can do a PURGE request, and remove the specific path from the CDN.

### But, how to work with wildcards or query strings?

It seems that the Firebase CDN cache has different keys for all variations of a URL. If I would e.g. issue a request to a specific URL with a PURGE method:

`curl -X PURGE https://my.firebasehosting.site.com/path/to/content`

This will purge the CDN cache for that URL, but not for `https://my.firebasehosting.site.com/path/to/content?someAdditionalStuffHere`

What would the way to PURGE urls at locations like:

- https://my.firebasehosting.site.com/path/to/content
- https://my.firebasehosting.site.com/path/to/content?someAdditionalStuffHere
- https://my.firebasehosting.site.com/path/to/content?width=200&height=100
- https://my.firebasehosting.site.com/path/to/**
- etc?

...**In one go**, without knowing all variants that have been generated? Is this even possible?

Comment: I don't know how to do it with a request as you said, but you may consider the following: using the firebase cli you can deploy static assets to a single site. The deploy works uploading all assets from a local folder to the CDN. Now, you can put just one empty file into it (or subfolder) and your CDN side will follow. Since cli commands are available also from API, you can replicate the behavior and clean up your remote folder.

Comment: Yeah, I already found out that a Firebase hosting redeploy would purge all CDN. However, I just want to purge a smaller part of the urls.